# select information from 2 columns in the same table depending on the values of other columns in the table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with the columns A, B, C, D, E, the E column have the value 0 or 1, so, I want to make a query that show me this info, this info depend of the value of the column E

A, B, C
A, B, D

for example

select * from table if E = 0
  A, B, C
else
 A, B, D

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use `CASE WHEN` to decide between `C` and `D`

```
select
   A,
   B,
   CASE WHEN E=0
     THEN C
   ELSE D
   END CASE
from 
  my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       C,
       'E=0'
FROM   my_table
WHERE  E = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT A,
       B,
       D,
       'E=1'
FROM   my_table
WHERE  E = 1
```